# How to prove the solution of these inequalities is empty?

Tags: inequality, vectors, normed-spaces, combinatorial-geometry, solid-geometry

Prove: There does not exist 4 unit vectors $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$, $\mathbf{v}_3$, $\mathbf{v}_4$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$$
\left \{ \ 
\begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac{4}{3} < \left \|\mathbf{v}_i + \mathbf{v}_j \right \| _2 ^2 < \dfrac{8}{3} \, , \\
\dfrac{4}{3} < \left \|\mathbf{v}_i - \mathbf{v}_j \right \| _2 ^2 < \dfrac{8}{3} \, ,
\end{array}
\ \  \forall\, 1\le i<j\le 4
\right.
.
$$

Note: It's preferred to prove it with algebra rather than high-level geometric concept.

Comment: If we have a solution $\left(\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3,\mathbf{v}_4\right)$ is a solution, then for any $i=1,2,3,4$, the assignment $\mathbf{v}_i\mapsto-\mathbf{v}_i$ still makes the tuple a solution.  Hence, it suffices to assume that all the $\mathbf{v}_i$'s lie within a single hemisphere.  We may also assume that two of the $\mathbf{v}_i$'s are on the boundary.

Comment: Then, we can transform this problem into a combinatorial geometry question (equivalent to the original setting).  "Let there be $6$ points on a unit hemisphere.  Prove that there is a pair which is less than $\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$ unit distance apart."  This is pretty much a spherical packing problem on a hemisphere.  Maybe, this related problem will help: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCode.html.

Comment: You have to edit because if, for example, the unit vectors $v_i$ are equal then....

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, take $$\mathbf{v}_1=(0,0,1)$$

Let $\displaystyle \mathbf{v}_{k}=\left( \sqrt{1-z_k^2}\cos \theta_{k},\sqrt{1-z_k^2}\sin \theta_{k},z_{k} \right)$ where $k=2,3,4$

$$|\mathbf{v}_1-\mathbf{v}_k|^2=2(1-z_k)$$

$$\frac{4}{3}< 2(1-z_k) < \frac{8}{3}$$

$$-\frac{1}{3} < z_{k} < \frac{1}{3}$$

To minimize $|\mathbf{v}_m-\mathbf{v}_n|$ for $2 \le m < n \le 4$, take $z_{k}=z$ and $\displaystyle \theta_{k}=\frac{2\pi k}{3}$

(We don't need to check for the case when $\theta_{m}=\theta_{n}$ since $|\mathbf{v}_{m}-\mathbf{v}_{n}|^2 < (\frac{2}{3})^2$ is smaller than the greatest lower bound.)

Now
$$|\mathbf{v}_m-\mathbf{v}_n|^2=3(1-z^2)$$

But $$\frac{8}{3} < 3(1-z^2) \le 3$$

That is $|\mathbf{v}_j-\mathbf{v}_k|$ is strictly larger than the least upper bound.

Contradiction.